# Conversion from Matlab Timestamp Date to Python Timestamp Date

Tags: python, matlab, date, numpy, matrix

I have a timestamp Matrix with (72500, 1) dimension in MATLAB. I have written such a statement in MATLAB:

```
returnMatrix = datestr(M(:,1)/86400 + datenum(1970,1,1)- 4/24);
```

And I successfully get the output date matrix back as a return Matrix.

```
returnMatrix = ['29/06/2015',...,'06/07/2015']
```

In order to get the same output, I have written such a statement in Python:

```
returnMatrix = (M[:, 0] / 86400 + date.toordinal(date(1970, 1, 1)) + 366 - (4/24))
returnMatrix = np.apply_along_axis((lambda x:[date.fromtimestamp(x[0]).strftime("%d/%m/%y")]),1,returnMatrix)
```

But as an output, I get this result:

```
returnMatrix = ['09/01/1970',...,'09/01/1970']
```

How should I write the statement in order to get the output as the one in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from this question is that you have data in seconds which you want to add to the base date which is 1/1/1970 and get the new date. Python 'timedelta' method from 'datetime' module will be handy to solve this problem.

Here I present my solution to your problem

```
    import datetime
    base_date = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)
    return_matrix = []
    for time in M:
        return_matrix.append(base_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time))
```

The return matrix will contain all the dates. No need for additional calculation.

I assume the data is saved in list M. I don't understand the way you are using python list. The way you have accessed the list i.e M[:0] will actually split the list from zeroth element to zeroth element excluding the zeroth. If it is a one dimensional data then you can directly use M the way I have used. I think you got confused there coming from a MATLAB background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sharad. I will let you know after trying your solution. But there is no other way to write it by using lambda? Because for loop takes so much time to process.

Comment: I can't say with surety about lambda because I haven't used it.

Comment: list comprehension can be another solution for the problem. you can create a list in this way:        return_matrix = [base_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time) for time in M]

Comment: @Sharad It seems like OP is using a two-dimensional [NumPy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) for M by analogy to how it would work in Matlab. The indexing in his example is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't used numpy so had no idea

Answer (score 0):

Given `M` is a `numpy` array containing seconds, you can do this, if you can live with having your date strings in ISO8601 format

```
dates = (M*numpy.timedelta64(1, 's') + 
         numpy.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00') -
         numpy.timedelta64(4, 'h').astype('timedelta64[s]')).astype('datetime64[D]')
```

(that `.astype` is there to squelch a warning about implicit conversion).